# Error message in PowerApps saying I don't have internet connection, which I have (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, form-customization

I am backfilling for someone and for this list she customized a standard SP form for the list.  I need to make some changes to the form, but when I click on Customize in PowerApps the screen loads and eventually I get this message: "Unable to Create App.  The request was not sent or there was no response from the server.  Check your internet connection."  I'm connected to the internet, and have a strong signal.  Nobody else has reported any server issues.  Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the issue that you mentioned, I think this issue may not be related to PowerApps Itself. Please check if your Company's Network have blocked the access to PowerApps service.

There are some Required services in PowerApps, please make sure your Company's Network does not block these services:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/limits-and-config#required-services